# Does continuity of all partial derivatives imply continuity of all directional derivatives?

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Let $X \subset \mathbb R^n$, $f:X\to\mathbb R^m$, $x_0\in X$

Assumption: All partial derivatives of f at $x_0$ exist and are continuous

$\Rightarrow$ f is differentiable at $x_0$.

$\Rightarrow D_vf(x_0)=\nabla f(x_0)\cdot v$ (assuming $m=1$ for simplicity)

Which means that all directional derivatives of f at $x_0$ can be expressed as linear combination of the (continuous) partial derivatives of f at $x_0$

Therefore these directional derivatives also have to be continuous. (*)

Is the conclusion correct? (Or why not?)
And if yes, is my proof correct? (Or why not?)

(*) I'm implicitly assuming that differentiability at $x_0$ implies differentiability at all points around $x_0$ if they are close enough. Only with this assumption I can conclude that the partial derivatives are defined around $x_0$ and therefore ask if they are continuous around $x_0$ or not.

I hope you can follow my thoughts. Else just ask for clarifications, it's my first question.
Thank you for your help :)

Comment: I believe continuity of partial derivatives implies existence of the derivative and hence all directional derivatives. You can see Spivak's 'Calculus on Manifolds' theorem 2.8

Comment: Yes, I understand that: continuous partial derivatives => differentiability <=> differential exists => directional derivatives exist. But are the directional derivatives continuous?

Comment: If you assume f has continuous partial derivatives at A open, then it has a continuous differential in A, hence the directional derivatives are also continuous.

Comment: In your proof, to be safe, I would've used the fact f is continuously differentiable.

Comment: You need to tell us more about $X.$

Comment: @zhw jep, i forgot to explicitly state that X is an open set. (It should implicitly follow from my assumption right?)
@NL1992(1) thank you, that's the thing i wasn't entirely sure about it.
@NL1992(2) Jep, that way works too: all partial derivatives continuous => continuous differential <=> continuously differentiable => all partial derivatives continuous